# iOS : How to push DDMenuController from UIButton not load from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to call `DDMenuController` from inner screen through `UIButton` click event of my app. when i am doing it will create double navigation bar as par the  image. can someone help me to do this.

attached[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a `UIViewController` should not produce a double Navigation Bar effect unless one is added after loading the view, and not as part of the application's `UINavigationController`. Nevertheless, you can Push a `UIViewController` using,

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES/NO];
```

If your `UIViewController` is designed using Storyboard, then you can call it by using the following code. (Remember to set the Storyboard Identifier of your `DDMenuController` to something, as it will be using in the following code.)

```
//Add this to the top of your page with the other imports.
#import "DDMenuController.h"

//Add this to the selector called by your UIButton.
DDMenuController *ddMenu = (DDMenuController *)[[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DDMenuVC"];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:ddMenu animated:YES/NO];
```

Comment: When i am pushing DDMenu from your first line, its work fine with single navigation but at the time when i m open leftview just slide view not navigation controller... (I am not using storyboard)

Comment: Are you using a UISplitViewController?

Comment: Are you using sliding views then? As you're referring to a "left view" and a "slide view".